# How do I add a record to a database with LINQ?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have been utilizing [Scott Gu's tutorials on LINQ to SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) to try to learn some LINQ.  I have been able to view, retrieve, and update records but I am unable to write new records into the database (MSSQL). Scott starts getting into inserting rows in the [fourth section](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/11/linq-to-sql-part-4-updating-our-database.aspx) of the set of tutorials. As you can see on that page (or may already know), in order to add a record you must do the following (VB.NET):

```
Dim db as New LINQtoSQLDataContext

Dim oArticle as New article // table name
oArticle.Body = "Some Text"
oArticle.Title = "Some Title"
oArticle.Author = "Some Author"

db.articles.Add(oArticle) // this is the line that does not work.
```

Visual Studio 2008 returns me "`'add' is not a member of 'System.Data.Linq.Table(Of article)`".

Can anyone give me a push in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
db.articles.InsertOnSubmit(oArticle)
db.SubmitChanges()
```

Comment: db.articles.InsertOnSubmit(oArticle)

Comment: haha. the solution is always so simple and/or right in front of me. thanks